# Draw tangent line on curve with MatLab

Tags: matlab, curve

Can some one help me to find a tangent for a curve.
I have two data set (time, temp). Now I first fit this data using logarithmic function and now I want to draw a tangent over mouse click. I upload a code which is useful but I am not aware how to modify this. Thanks for help.

```
function test

    hh = figure(1); clf, hold on
    grid on
    x = 0:0.01:2*pi;
    f = @(x) sin(x);
    fprime = @(x) cos(x);

    plot(x, f(x), 'r')
    axis tight

    D = [];
    L = [];
    set(hh, ...
        'WindowButtonMotionFcn', @mouseMove,...
        'WindowButtonDownFcn', @mouseClick);


    function mouseMove(varargin)

        coords = get(gca, 'currentpoint');
        xC = coords(1);

        if ishandle(D)
            delete(D); end
        D = plot(xC, f(xC), 'ko');

    end

    function mouseClick(obj, varargin)

        switch get(obj, 'selectiontype')

            % actions for left mouse button
            case 'normal' 

                coords = get(gca, 'currentpoint');
                xC = coords(1);
                yC = f(xC);

                a  = fprime(xC);
                b  = yC-a*xC;

                if ishandle(L)
                    delete(L); end
                L = line([0; 2*pi], [b; a*2*pi+b]);

            case 'alt'    
                % actions for right mouse button

            case 'extend' 
                % actions for middle mouse button

            case 'open'   
                % actions for double click

            otherwise
                % actions for some other X-mouse-whatever button

        end

    end

end
```

Comment: "I upload a code which is useful but I am not aware how to modify this" I think you already found the answer, just change the sin wave to your log-regression?

Comment: %in my case,                                                                                          %y is time;                                                                                             %x is temp;                                                                                                       x = temp(1:end);
    f = @a*logb(x); %b is 10 assume.
    fprime = @a./x;   does not looks good.